# Blender overwrite my animation

Tags: rendering, animation

When creating a new animation during Blender rendering, it overwrites it to the old file. It seems to be fixed by the parameter "overwrite", but I simply don't have it

[image]

Comment: Hey there, this is intended functionality. Unless you set a *new* file as the output, the old file will always be overridden

Comment: @josephhansen That's just half the truth ;) The option _Overwrite_ is available (and enabled by default) when you render image sequences such as PNGs etc. The reason for this is if you have an animation of for example 200 frames, you could render the first 100 frames, then pause and continue rendering without having to change the start and end frame of your animation. Another possibility is rendering on multiple PCs to speed up rendering, without having all PCs render the same frames and overwriting the others. This doesn't work with video files because they have to be rendered completely.